# setBackgroundResource() takes a lot of time to show in kotlin/android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using setBackgroundResource to set the background of each cell in a layout on click.Depending on the condition different background drawables are set for the cells.

But this takes a lot of time,sometimes when I click cell4 nothing happens and then when I click cell6,cell4 background is changed,and sometimes it changes after a long time. How can I fix this?

I have attached part of my code below:

```js
if(cell.getTag()==11){
            cell.isSelected=false
            cell.setTag(0xFFFFFFFF.toInt())
            textView.setTextColor(0xFF87CEEB.toInt())
            cell.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bordered_rectangle)
}
else if(isChecked || cell.getTag()==22) {
            cell.isSelected=true
            cell.setTag(11.toInt())
            textView.setTextColor(0xFF000000.toInt())                                      
            cell.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_boardselect)
}
```

R.drawable.bordered_rectangle

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
<stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#ff444444" />
<padding android:left="2dp"
    android:top="2dp"
    android:right="2dp"
    android:bottom="2dp" />
<!--<solid android:color="#ffffff" />-->

    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:endColor="#87CEEB"
        android:centerColor="#768087"
        android:startColor="#000"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

I have tried putting the drawable in drawable-nodpi folder.I don't know what else to do.

Really need some help here.

Comment: How big is the resource?  If it is really big I would try shrinking it to match the DPI of the devices you would be running on.

Comment: @Shawn I have updated my code above with drawable file codes.Please check and let me know what is to be done?

Comment: I was going on the assumption that they were images so I don't think my previous suggestion is applicable.

Comment: This can be challenging to debug.  Hopefully someone who has more experience than me can chime in and point out a specific issue.  If it were me I would start diving into how setBackgroundResource works and figure out where the delay is coming from.
A few helpful resources:
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler - shows how long methods take

http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/View.java#21444 - look at the actual implementation of the android framework.

And finally just android studio debug.

Comment: ok,no problem!!

Answer (score 0):

It might be just an assumption, but it might be the Gradient.

However, from your code, I'd suggest you use a Selector rather than 2 different Drawables. That will at least make the code smaller and less confusing.

And what is your view? The view itself might have a hard time drawing backgrounds since background are very heavy compared to Images.

Comment: My drawables are very small in size.Actually i am not sure but this error happens only on genymotion,i tried on android cell and emulator but did not come across this error.Is this a genymotion error?

Comment: Genymotion isn't a reference for testing. The Android AVD is a far better reference. But if the issue doesn't appear on a physical device, then yes, assume that Genymotion has an issue.